# Passing variables to perl modules in nginx.conf

Tags: perl, nginx

I am writing an Nginx configuration that calls a perl script with some Nginx variables as argumetns and returns a value to the script as if the Nginx.conf is the main for this perl script. I have enabled the perl module on Nginx and run a helloworld successfully from the nginx configuration. As a newbie with perl can you help me to know what's wrong with this 
here is my test.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub function {
    my $r = shift;
    my $foo = $r->variable('foo');
    print $foo;
}
```

and this is how i call it on my Nginx.conf

```
 set $foo 100;
 perl My::function ;
```

and this what i get on my console

```
nginx: [emerg] require_pv("test.pm") failed: "test.pm did not return a true value   at     (eval 1) line 1."
```

if i change my nginx conf like this

```
 perl My::function 100 ;
```

i get

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "perl" directive in /usr/local/nginx  /conf/nginx.conf:22
```

Comment: have you tried adding a '1;' as the last line of the .pm file? perl modules are supposed to return a true value.

Comment: after adding '1;' i don't have any errors on my console but i don't have any output neither so the function call was never made

Answer (score 0):

You want $r->print instead of just print as well as the 1; at the end